# Print values from selected "li" tags in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to learning about JQuery and would appreciate any assistance and guidance on how to achieve the following goal:

On my website, I have a list of selectable choices (Each selectable choice is created using `<li>` tags.

e.g.

```
<li class="number" show-value="1">option 1</li>
<li class="number" show-value="2">option 2</li>
<li class="number" show-value="3">option 3</li>
```

I then have a `div` with the following structure:

```
<div id="shownumberlist"></div>
```

What I want to achieve here is to be able to show a list of all numbers that are selected (on-click) and this list needs to update if someone clicks on one of their selected choices to remove it from the list.

I want the selected number list to display in the `shownumberlist` div.

Thank you :-)

Comment: You'll need to start by actually storing your "selected" status somewhere. Instead of rolling your own custom solution for that, I would use checkboxes for that (can be visually hidden, if desired.) The text content of your items would then get wrapped into a `label`, so that clicking on it automatically toggles the checkbox. Then you can use `:checked` in your jQuery selection to get all the checked checkboxes. You could go from there to the parent `li` to then grab the `show-value` attribute content - or you make that the `value` of the checkboxes to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a study of this

1. toggle a select class on click
2. on same click I map the li.selected in the ul
3. fill the div with the joined array

I would personally use data-value instead of show-value since data attributes are the standard way to do this

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  const $showList = $("#shownumberlist");
  $("#list").on("click", function(e) { // delegate from list. I could use $(".number") too 
    $(e.target).toggleClass("selected"); // something clicked
    $showList.text($(".selected", this).map(function() {  // the "this" is the UL
        return $(this).attr("show-value")
      }).get() // the array
      .join(", ") /// join with comma
    );
  })
})
```

```css
#list {width: 100px; }
.selected { border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li class="number" show-value="1">option 1</li>
  <li class="number" show-value="2">option 2</li>
  <li class="number" show-value="3">option 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="shownumberlist"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much @mplungjan - I really appreciate your thorough explanation. I've saved  your code to help me strengthen my skills based on the comments you have listed within your code structure. I'm still in the very early days of learning everything yet, but I most appreciate the time you have taken to share your wisdom with me :-) Thank you!